# Django: dumpdata cannot connect to database

Tags: django

We have a legacy Django application and I am trying to migrate the old app to a new location. The Django version is 2.2. I want to execute `dumpdata` command to load the output fixture to the new location. The old machine containing the app has default configurations for database i.e. it is using a PostreSQL installed in the same machine and use `localhost` as address.

When running `dumpdata`, I cannot seem to connect to the database.

```
(venv) software# python manage.py dumpdata > dump.json
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I also tried the command `python manage.py inspectdb` to check the connection and it is still not able to connect. I can access the admin page of the app and can view details which is a clear indicator that database is running well and can index what is on the admin page.

Why am I getting this error? Could it be I am using wrong machine user?

Comment: Try python manage dbshell and it is expected to fail as well. Is this application live and kicking?

Comment: The application is live @MohamedElKalioby.

Comment: What about python manage.py dbshell

Comment: how does your `manage.py` look like and how does `DATABASES` in settings look like?